# Combining GPX tracks in QGIS

Tags: qgis, buffer, heat-map, gpx

I have several GPX tracks on the same road and I would like to average out a heatmap of velocities from these GPX tracks on this road.

I think I figured out a way to do this in QGIS - in theory.

I already know how to import the individual points in GPX format and have them linked trough line segments. What I need help with is using this to turn it into a heatmap.

I think the best idea would be to use buffer on the road lines and then segment them along their axes (like chopping it into pieces). Then I could easily use "join attributes by location (summary)" and be done with this. But I dont know how to segment the buffered roads (from OSM) and I dont know how to remove overlapping buffers at intersections. With this I really need help.

Comment: Have you tried GPS Babel? It has some filtering options https://www.gpsbabel.org/htmldoc-1.7.0/Data_Filters.html

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which explains how our Focused question/Best answer model operates. Questions seeking "thoughts", "input" and "ideas" are more *discussion-oriented* than is usually permitted here, especially when also asking about what could be multiple topics.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.  Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works. Thanks.